# How can I get (x,y,z) data from point cloud structure data obtained from kinect sensor in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, kinect, matlab-figure, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I plot point cloud figure in MATLAB using Kinect-V2 camera. I determined three markers in the MATLAB figure using the Data cursor tool to get the (x,y,z) of these points. Then, I saved these data as a (.mat file). When I open it again, I found that MATLAB saves the data of each marker in structure array.

How can I get again (x,y,z) of these markers from the Structure arrays?

Attached to the question link of the structure arrays that related to each of the markers.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/yxhjjxh0l312iuz/matlab.mat

Comment: Hi , You have a figure(.fig) and want to extract data from it?

Comment: No, I save these data before closing the figure. Now, I just have the structure arrays of 3- point clouds not the figure.

Comment: i think maybe you save data in not appropriate way. you can save your data by this commands 1- h=gca   2-axesObjs=get(h,'Children');  3- x=axesObjs.XData,y=axesObjs.YData,z=axesObjs.ZData;

Answer (score 0):

Don't really wanna download from an external link so I will have to guess how it looks.

Is it setup like this

```
--> mydata
      --> X
          value
      --> Y
          value
      --> Z 
          value
```

If it is setup in this manner then all you have to do is write a basic code to extract out the values

```
 data = [mydata.X, mydata.Y, mydata.Z];
```

Comment: No, it's struct array like the following. This related to only one marker.



1x1 Scatter
 
 [-0.871160447597504,0.780648231506348,2.43500018119812]
1x1 Scatter
 
 [-0.763933300971985,0.912683129310608,2.34800004959107]
1x1 Scatter
 
 [-0.876266658306122,0.911082625389099,2.41000008583069]